# Является ли дочерним элементом элемента элемент?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как проверить, является ли элемент дочерним?
Пример: есть grid, в нём rectangle(A), а в rectangle(A) ещё один rectangle(B). Так вот, в коде у меня есть rectangle(B) как `Uielement Box;` появился он у меня там : после того как я создал его `Rectangle newboxb = new Rectangle;` я его пихаю в `Public Uielement chld = newboxb`. И вот как определить что chld является дочерним grid-a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки можно использовать метод `Contains`:

```
box.Children.Contains(newboxb)
```

Или проверять `Parent`:

```
newboxb.Parent == box
```

И точно так же надо и добавлять:

```
box.Children.Add(newboxb);
```

Если вы просто положите член класса, он не будет никем замечен, и проинтерпретирован как объект.

Впрочем, с более высокоуровневой точки зрения вы не должны добавлять элементы вручную, а пользоваться XAML'ом.

---

Если вам нужно проверить, является ли элемент вложенным на нескольких уровнях, лучше, наверное, такой код:

```
bool IsContainedDeep(FrameworkElement outer, FrameworkElement inner)
{
    for (var current = inner.Parent as FrameworkElement;
         current != null;
         current = current.Parent as FrameworkElement)
    {
        if (current == outer)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: оно сработает если дочерний объект будет трижды дочерним?

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Нет. Сейчас напишу вариант, как искать на всех уровнях.

Comment: хорошо, я был бы очень вам благодарен )

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: готово.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, кстати помните тот пост где у меня была проблема с "только чтением", так вот я попробовал заменить ellipse(на том на котором вылазила ошибка) на rectangle и всё стало работать на "ура" :D

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Пожалуйста! Насчёт ellipse/rectangle интересный эффект, надо будет подумать, почему.